# RangeError [ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE]: The value of "value" is out of range. It must be >= 0 and <= 4294967295. Received 9433906525

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express, sequelize.js

I'm getting this range error for a value I am not inserting.

```
const createTransaction = async (yodleeAccountId, transaction) => {
  try {
    const savedRecord = await YodleeTransaction.create({
      YodleeAccountID: 373,
      YodleeID: 1887219837,
      Amount: 40518.32,
      AmountCurrency: 'USD',
      BaseType: 'CREDIT',
      Container: 'bank',
      PostDate: '2016-03-19',
      OriginalDescription: 'info about transaction',
      SimpleDescription: 'info',
      CategoryID: '2',
      Category: 'giving idk',
      CategoryType: 'the important type',
    })
    console.log('post create')
    return savedRecord
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('error finally caught', error)
    return error
  }
}
```

YodleeTransaction model:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, type) => {
  return sequelize.define(
    'YodleeTransaction',
    {
      ID: { type: type.BIGINT, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
      YodleeAccountID: { type: type.BIGINT, allowNull: false },
      YodleeID: { type: type.BIGINT, allowNull: false },
      Amount: { type: type.DECIMAL(12, 2), allowNull: false },
      AmountCurrency: { type: type.STRING(3) },
      BaseType: { type: type.STRING(25), allowNull: false },
      Container: { type: type.STRING(50) },
      PostDate: { type: type.DATE, allowNull: false },
      OriginalDescription: { type: type.STRING(800) },
      SimpleDescription: { type: type.STRING(500) },
      CategoryID: { type: type.INTEGER },
      Category: { type: type.STRING(50) },
      CategoryType: { type: type.STRING(50) },
    },
    { freezeTableName: true, tableName: 'YodleeTransaction' }
  )
}
```

Error:

> RangeError [ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE]: The value of "value" is out of range. It must be >= 0 and <= 4294967295. Received 9433906525

I know that 9433906525 is somehow based on the `Amount` because when I change the `Amount`, the value in the error message changes.
For example if I change Amount from 40518.32 to 8989.33 the new value received is 10728568304.
New error:

> RangeError [ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE]: The value of "value" is out of range. It must be >= 0 and <= 4294967295. Received 10728568304

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Sequelize.
Doing too many insertions or updates asynchronously causes this to happen.
I don't know specifically how to resolve this issue, but I can tell you how to get around it.

The solution to the above create error is to use `bulkCreate` and pass it an array of objects.

If you are doing updates with t-sql then Sequelize does not provide a `bulkUpdate` methods. So you should just manually write out the update query inside `sequelize.query('UPDATE YodleeTransaction SET Amount=344.88')`.

Comment: It appears to be related to this: https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious/issues/474.

Comment: I'd like to point that I have the same issue in my project which doesn't use Sequelize. On looking for existing issues, I've come to think it's a Buffer issue in my case, which (maybe) is similar to what Sequelize uses internally.

Comment: @roshnet Well it was something going on with tedious.